# Does xliff 1.2 supports custom annotations

Tags: xliff

I am working on a sample file in Xliff 1.2 but confused with annotation.As I didnot find anywhere whether it supports custom annotation or not?

Can anyone refer links for sample xliff1.2 file with annotations(if it supports any kind of annotations)

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the `annotates` attribute in XLIFF 1.2? Or are you asking about extending XLIFF by adding your own elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
you can read more about this in the following link:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/xliff-core.html#note

This is an example:


<xliff version="1.2">
 <file original="Graphic Example.psd"
  source-language="en-US" target-language="ja-JP"
  tool="Rainbow" datatype="photoshop">
  <header>
   <skl>
    <external-file uid="3BB236513BB24732" href="Graphic Example.psd.skl"/>
   </skl>
   <phase-group>
    <phase phase-name="extract" process-name="extraction"
     tool="Rainbow" date="20010926T152258Z"
     company-name="NeverLand Inc." job-id="123"
     contact-name="Peter Pan" contact-email="ppan@example.com">
     <note>Make sure to use the glossary I sent you yesterday.
      Thanks.</note>
    </phase>
   </phase-group>
  </header>
  <body>
   <trans-unit id="1" maxbytes="14">
    <source xml:lang="en-US">Quetzal</source>
    <target xml:lang="ja-JP">Quetzal</target>
   </trans-unit>
   <trans-unit id="3" maxbytes="114">
    <source xml:lang="en-US">An application to manipulate and 
     process XLIFF documents</source>
    <target xml:lang="ja-JP">XLIFF 文書を編集、または処理
     するアプリケーションです。</target>
   </trans-unit>
   <trans-unit id="4" maxbytes="36">
    <source xml:lang="en-US">XLIFF Data Manager</source>
    <target xml:lang="ja-JP">XLIFF データ・マネージャ</target>
   </trans-unit>
  </body>
 </file>
</xliff>
```